# Question on normal and binomial distribution.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

The lifetimes of phone batteries are normally distributed with a mean of $23$ hours. They are sold in packs of $100$ to phone manufacturers. The manufacturer of the batteries aims to make batteries with more consistent lifetimes. Their target is to claim that the probability that a pack contains at least one battery with a lifetime of less than $22$ hours is below 5%. For the manufacturer to meet this target determine

(a) the minimum value of the probability of a randomly chosen battery lasting longer than $22$ hours to six decimal places

(b) the maximum expected number of batteries out of $1,000,000$ batteries with a lifetime of less than $22$ hours

(c) the maximum value of the standard deviation of the lifetime of the batteries

**My solution**

(a) $$1-P(X>22)^{100}<0.05$$
$$P(X>22)>0.95^{1/100}$$
$$P(X>22)>0.9994872$$

So the minimum value of $P(X>22)=0.999487$ .

(b) $$E(Y)=np=1000000(1-0.999487)=513$$

(c) We know that $P(X<22)=1-0.999487=0.00513$ So

$$\frac{22-23}{\sigma}=invNorm(0.000513,0,1)$$
$${\sigma}=2.566941$$

Are my solutions above correct?

Comment: You might want to check (c), which looks implausibly large to me

Comment: @Henry Do you have any suggestion what went wrong? I checked the steps and they looked correct to me. But just like what you mentioned, the value looks too large.

Comment: What was your $invNorm(0.000513,0,1)$?  Is it equal to $\frac{22-23}{2.566941}$?  If not then your ${\sigma}=2.566941$ looks wrong

Comment: @Henry Oh yes, I got you. Many thanks. $\sigma$ should be $0.304572$. Do you think there are any other mistakes in my solutions for (a), (b) and (c)?